# boost shared_ptr get owner count

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm using boost::shared_ptr to store a pointer to texture. I'm loading new textures as i need and share them among the program using shared_ptr. If my app is using too much memory i want to remove unused textures to clear memory. Is there a way I can determine how many objects are  having access to the texture via shared_ptr ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's unused then the `shared_ptr` will free it automatically. That's the point of `shared_ptr`. If you are holding a `shared_ptr` to a texture without actually using it, then you're violating the contract of `shared_ptr` and should not be using it.

Comment: All textures are held by a ResourceManager via shared_ptr. And any other parts of the program are having access to textures via this manager. I don't want to remove the textures until i recieve a memory warning. In this case i want to remove unused texture (that are held only by resource manager)

Comment: @Andrew: did you have a look at boost.weak_ptr or boost.intrusive_ptr ?

Comment: @Andrew: It'd be easier to just drop the ResourceManager and leave `shared_ptr` to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`shared_ptr::use_count()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#use_count), but read the documentation before doing so!

Answer (score 1):

There is [`use_count()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#use_count), however note that as the documentation says, it's not necessarily too efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The `shared_ptr` class has member functions `use_count()` and `unique()` to give you access to its usage count.

It's a different question how that information will be useful to you, though.